# How to remove "brianium/paratest" when upgrade Laravel 9 -> 10?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have a project in Laravel **9**. I am trying to upgrade it to Laravel **10**.

I followed the documentation for the upgrade, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#upgrade-10.0) .

But when I run the composer update I have this error :

```
Problem 1
- brianium/paratest[v6.4.0, ..., v6.4.1] require phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.10 -> found phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.6.7] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.0).
- brianium/paratest v6.4.2 requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.13 -> found phpunit/phpunit[9.5.13, ..., 9.6.7] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.0).
```

and many other errors regarding "brianium/paratest".

The documentation explains that the phpunit version must be ^10.0.

I already tried `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` without success.

How to do ?

Comment: `composer remove brianum/paratest`  should remove that package. Otherwise, why not update that package? v6.4.2 is more than a year old

Comment: I updated `brianium/paratest` to 7.1 and after the upgrade laravel 9 --> 10 is OK.  thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dom: Hint for next time: `composer update --with-all-dependencies` tells composer to update even those dependencies that you have in your root requirements.  So you can make your Laravel (or which ever package) update _leading_ and then composer tries to update everything else to make your command happen.